# Error loading my lightdm webkit greeter theme

Tags: gtk, themes, webkit

I made a minimal theme but it doesn't work.
Here is the index.theme:

```
[theme]
name=ramana
description=Ramana Maharshi lightdm webkit2 theme
engine=lightdm-webkit2-greeter
url=index.html
session=awesome
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css' class='style'>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    hi
</body>
</html>
```

css/style.css:

```
body {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

The theme is located at /usr/share/lightdm-webkit/themes/ramana
Lightdm-webkit2-greeter.conf has webkit_theme set to ramana
I don't even see the error in the /var/log/lightdm logs!

And there is no documentation, only the glorious topic and I looked at it and it seems that I did everything right

I tried to study glorious but did not understand what was missing for work